# Form submission not changing data

Tags: php

I am having issues submitting on `li` the code is submitting just that my data is not changing. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$theme1 = business;
$theme2 = modern;
$theme3 = web2;
if(isset($_POST['style']))
{setcookie('style', $_POST['style'], time()+(60*60*24*1000));
$style=$_POST['style'];}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['style']))
{$style=$_COOKIE['style'];}
else
{$style=$theme1;} 

echo "
<link href='"; $style; echo".css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<form  action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post' id='myForm'>
<li onclick='myForm.submit();' value='$theme1'> business</li>
</form>

";
?>
```

The code does submit on the website but it is not changing the data. The form was made using the select option style. Here is the code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post"> 
<select name="style"> 
<option type="submit" <?php echo "value='$theme1'";if($style == $theme1){echo    "selected='selected'";}?>><?php echo $theme1; ?></option>
<option type="submit" <?php echo "value='$theme2'";if($style == $theme2){echo "selected='selected'";}?>><?php echo $theme2; ?></option>
<option type="submit" <?php echo "value='$theme3'";if($style == $theme3){echo "selected='selected'";}?>><?php echo $theme3; ?></option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I think there is a problem with the `li` missing some information. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: sir, you need to get your basic php/html/mysql right.

Comment: You’re using `;` to separate things in your `echo`; they should be commas.

Comment: You’re not quoting your strings.

Comment: You’re not indenting your blocks or spacing your operators.

Comment: And `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is unsafe, use htmlspecialchars to remove dangerous chars!

Comment: *What is wrong with my code* isn't very descriptive. If you tell us what you're trying to do, maybe we can suggest a better way to do this. I'm sure this can be improved.

Comment: @minitech Whether it's unsafe or not, you can just use an empty action.

Comment: There are many things to correct... You should try addressing one problem at a time when asking and to do some debugging yourself first.

Comment: @minitech Yeah, assume his script name is `index.php`, attacker enters: `http://domain.com/index.php/"><script>alert(0);</script><form` in address bar   And Boooom!

Comment: Oh, and your `<li>` can’t have a `value`. Forms don’t work like that.

Comment: Still not working I must have been missing the name=style and the if ($style == $theme1)   Although starting with dotted for themes is a way to go its not working!

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of errors but here are some fixes

```
$theme1 = 'business';
$theme2 = 'modern';
$theme3 = 'web2'; //qoute strings
if(isset($_POST['style'])){
setcookie('style', $_POST['style'], time()+(60*60*24*1000));
    $style=$_POST['style'];
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['style'])){
$style=$_COOKIE['style'];
}else{
$style=$theme1;} 

echo "<link href='". $style . ".css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />"; //this line was way off
```

Comment: No, I meant in this one you have a quote and not a dot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here! The most relevant to your probable problem are:

- `; $style;` probably does not do what you think it does
- `<li value="…">` is meaningless and won’t get submitted with a form (and an `<li>` is not valid outside of a `<ul>` to begin with)

So here’s both of those fixed to use PHP’s tags and `<input type="submit">`, along with some code style changes — assuming you’re using PHP 5.4 or higher:

```
<?php
$themes = ['business', 'modern', 'web2'];
if(isset($_POST['style'])) {
    setcookie('style', $_POST['style'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
    $style = $_POST['style'];
} elseif(isset($_COOKIE['style'])) {
    $style = $_COOKIE['style'];
} else {
    $style = $themes[0];
} 
?>

<link href="<?= $style ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($themes as $theme): ?>
            <li><input type="submit" name="style" value="<?= $theme ?>" /></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

May I also recommend not using POST? If someone tries to refresh the page, it’ll be annoying. GET is just as good for this kind of thing, and links are easier to style than buttons.

Comment: That did not work either. It looks like something foreach is around that  style but its not workign

Comment: @user2692270: So what does the page look like? Any PHP errors? Do you have them turned on?

Comment: I believe I am missing the syntax ;if($style == $theme1)

Comment: @user2692270: Nope, unless your stylesheets aren’t named `business.css`, `modern.css`, and `web2.css`. Also, are your stylesheets in the same directory? Is the problem that they’re not loading?

Comment: Not even the code just adds the word at the beginning business or modern

Comment: @user2692270: At the beginning of what?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. You missed to assign the variable in li. Change the following code and while assigning the value to the variable ($theme1, $theme2, $theme3), assign the value using single quote as all are string.

```
echo "<link href='" . $style . ".css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /><form  action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "' method='post' id='myForm'><li onclick='myForm.submit();' value='" . $theme1 . "'>" . $style . "</li></form>";
```

Note: Here instead of static value "business", change it to $style variable.